# How does Blazor handle sharing data among multiple components and nested components?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I have a Blazor app with many components, and nested components that I would like to share data among, but I cannot figure out how to do this efficiently. Here is, sort of, what I have:

**MyProject.Pages.Index.razor:**

```
@page "/"
<div>
    @if(some_state) {
        <ComponentAlpha @bind-something=Something />
    else if(some_other_state){
        <ComponentBeta Something="Something" />
    } else {
        <ComponentGamma Something="Something" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    String Something { get; set; }
}
```

**MyProject.Shared.ComponentAlpha.razor:**

```
<div>
    Stuff here ...
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public String something { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<String> somethingChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task MyTask() {
        await somethingChanged.InvokeAsync(something);
    }
}
```

This all works fantastic for getting data from `ComponentAlpha.razor` back to `Index.razor`, and from `Index.razor` to `ComponentBeta.razor` and `ComponentGamma.razor`. My question comes in for **beyond** `ComponentBeta.razor` and `ComponentGamma.razor`.

**MyProject.Shared.ComponentBeta.razor:**

```
<div>
    Stuff here ...

    <ComponentDelta />

    <ComponentEpsilon />

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public String Something { get; set; }
}
```

**MyProject.Shared.ComponentGamma.razor:**

```
<div>
    Stuff here ...

    <ComponentZeta />

    <ComponentEta />

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public String Something { get; set; }
}
```

**MyProject.Shared.ComponentDelta.razor:**

**MyProject.Shared.ComponentEpsilon.razor:**

**MyProject.Shared.ComponentZeta.razor:**

**MyProject.Shared.ComponentEta.razor:**

```
<div>
    Stuff here ...

    <MoreAndMoreComponents />
</div>

@code {
    // I want to use variable "something" here as well.
}
```

In order to be able to share the string `something` amongst all my components and embedded components, do I need to jump through all the elaborate hoops that I did for just `Index.razor`, `ComponentAlpha.razor`, and `ComponentBeta.razor` or is there some better way?

I saw **[THIS](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/)** out there and thought option **3. State Container** would be my best bet, However, when I follow their example, I always end up with this Exception:

```
Error   CS0119  'AppState' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

So, what is the way we are supposed to use to efficiently share data amongst all components and nested components?

Comment: There are many approaches to managing state in Blazor, and I'd recommend at least looking into a [state management library like Fluxor](https://dev.to/mr_eking/advanced-blazor-state-management-using-fluxor-part-1-696) just to see if it might be a fit for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a service, probably Scoped.  You then inject the service into each component, you can use an Interface and/or base abstract class to boilerplate the code.  You can also use this same service for events - signalling that data has changed.

See the [MS Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly) on services and how to use/provision them.

Comment: I was going to say that as an answer... services are easy to set up and very flexible using the events for notifications. E.g. trigger an event on the Set of an object can loop round components that register for that event in their oninitialized  function.

Comment: I read through that MS Docs link you shared, but cannot see anything about "custom" services. I mean, I am wanting to pass my own objects around the app, not an HttpClient, IJSRuntime, or NavigationManager. There was something about a "custom service provider" but not any mention of how to do it; how to create a "custom service" that will let me pass around my objects.

Comment: @Brian There's a short post on my personal site here that describes a basic notification pattern service and wiring https://shauncurtis.github.io/posts/Notification-Service-Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

One option you can consider is using cascading parameters, which will allow a top level component to pass itself down to any child components regardless of component tree depth. It's very easy to set up.

#### In your top level component:

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="this">

    @*Note Component Alpha placement*@
    <ComponentAlpha />

</CascadingValue>

@code {

    private string something = "initial value";

    // this is a getter only for the property, but you can use
    // a setter for 2 way binding also. Just make sure
    // to modify the setter to run 'StateHasChanged()'
    // after updating the value, and then 
    // you can then set the property directly
    public string Something => something;

    // This will allow child components to set the new value
    public Task SetNewValue(string value)
    {
        something = value;
        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Note that the CascadingValue is passing `this` down the tree to it's children, so you can capture it where needed.

#### In the mid level (alpha) component

```cs
<div>
    <div @onclick="SetNewValue">@ValueFromTopLevel</div>

     @*Note Component Beta placement*@
    <ComponentBeta /> 
</div>

@code {

    // Capture the top level component here
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Component TopLevelComponent { get; set; }

    // pull out the value you need here
    public string ValueFromTopLevel => TopLevelComponent.Something;

    // use this to set a new value
    void SetNewValue()
    {
        TopLevelComponent.SetNewValue("Hello from Alpha component!");
    }
}
```

Notice the beta component nested inside the alpha component.

#### In the low level (beta for my example) component

```cs
<div>
    <div @onclick="SetNewValue">@ValueFromTopLevel</div>
</div>

@code {

    // still capture the top level component
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Component TopLevelComponent { get; set; }

    // use the value the same as Alpha
    public string ValueFromTopLevel => TopLevelComponent.Something;

    // set the value the same as Alpha
    void SetNewValue()
    {
        TopLevelComponent.SetNewValue("Hello from Beta component!");
    }
}
```

With this setup, by clicking on the text of either the Alpha or the Beta component, the value of `something` is updated at the top level and then the new value is cascaded down again with a fresh render. All the state management is at the top and the child components are just hooking in where needed.This setup will allow you to use methods and properties from a top level component as you see fit. For example I created a top level Toast Notification component once that wraps the whole app and can be captured and used anywhere. Simply pass it a message and a type (info, error, warning) and it displays the flash message for a few seconds and then hides again.

There are some downsides though, notably that your top level component needs to be responsible for all state management. This works for simpler scenarios, but as the app and the interactions become more complex this can get out of hand. However, if you *combine* this with Enet's answer and get the state management happening at the top, you can then hook in where needed down the component tree.

Also note that any child components become coupled to the top level parent as they will require being up the tree somewhere to work properly. Maybe Ok for you, maybe not. Either way, it's a good tool to be aware of.

Official docs for cascading parameters can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how permanent you need your info to be, and to what degree you're willing to hold global variables on the parent.

**1.  One trick is to pass the parent control to the children**-- give them full access to its variables:

**ParentControl**

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
  <ChildControl />
</CascadingValue>
```

**ChildControl**

```
[Parameter]
ParentControl Parent;
@code {
    Parent.SomeVariable = Something;
}
```

**2.  If you don't want to do that, then you can pass data to its parent using an `EventCallback<T>`**

**ChildControl**

```
@code
    {
    [Parameter]
    EventCallBack<MyCustomClass> OnDataReady { get; set; }
    MyCustomClass ActiveObject { get; set; }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        OnDataReady.InvokeAsync(ActiveObject);
    }
}
```

And on **ParentControl**:

```
<ChildControl OnDataReady=HandleData />
@code {
     async Task HandleData (MyCustomClass data){
       // Do stuff
     }
}
```

**3.**  If you REALLY want highly persistent data, then consider **saving state in a database**.  Since Blazor requires no postbacks, there's really no penalty for saving or loading information from a database whenever you want.

**4.  Using a service as per @enet's answer**